# Binding from Headers in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Can Spring MVC bind HTTP headers to Java classes?

I've got three headers, and I'd like to marshall them into a POJO, much like you'd do with a form or a request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two ways that you could achieve this with Spring and request or prototype scoped beans.

It is worth first being clear on the different [scopes of beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-request) and how Spring creates proxies for different scopes if you are not already.

The first method uses [Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) to directly reference the current HttpServletRequest instance.

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyClass
{
     @Value({#request.getHeader('headerName')})    
     private String myHeaderValue;

     public String getMyHeaderValue()
     {
            return myHeaderValue;
     }
}
```

An alternative is to simply inject the current HttpServletRequest as a constructor parameter:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyClass
{

     private String myHeaderValue;

     @Autowired 
     public MyClass(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
     {
           this.myHeaderValue = httpServletRequest.getHeader("headerValue");
     }

     public String getMyHeaderValue()
     {
           return this.myHeaderValue;
     }
 }
```

You can then inject this bean into your Controller or Service beans as needed:

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
       @Autowired   
       private MyClass myClass;
}
```

Either method should let you achieve what you want, you can pick which best suits your requirements and preferences.