# Duplication for RequestHeader in Java Spring Boot controllers

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

I have a working set of Rest controllers written in Java. The requirement was initially to add some headers for some endpoints, however we decided to add those header fields in almost ALL Rest controllers. Now the project contains more than 100 APIs similar to these:

```
@GetMapping("/products/{comp}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts(
        @RequestHeader(USER_HDR) String user,
        @RequestHeader(GUID_HDR) String guid,
        @RequestHeader(value = CALLER_HDR, required = false) String caller,
        @RequestHeader(value = LANG_HDR, required = false) String language,
        @PathVariable @NotNull Integer comp
) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.get(comp, ProductUtils.processHeaders(user,guid,caller,language)));

}

@GetMapping("/products")
public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts(
        @RequestHeader(USER_HDR) String user,
        @RequestHeader(GUID_HDR) String guid,
        @RequestHeader(value = CALLER_HDR, required = false) String caller,
        @RequestHeader(value = LANG_HDR, required = false) String language
) {

   return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getAllRecords(ProductUtils.processHeaders(user,guid,caller,language)));

}
```

It is obvious from the code that the tuple user, guid, caller, language exists everywhere in the source, however, is it not so obvious how to refactor and put the code in "one place" or try to make it more maintainable. If for example we need to add a 5th param, we need to go to 100 APIs.

Which is the canonical way to do this in Java Spring boot?

Ideally, I would like have something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/products/{comp}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts(
            "common handling"
            @PathVariable @NotNull Integer comp
    ) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.get(comp, ProductUtils.processHeaders(user,guid,caller,language)));

    }

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts(
            "common handling"
    ) {

       return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getAllRecords(ProductUtils.processHeaders(user,guid,caller,language)));

    }
```

Any idea? Controller Advice? Something else?

Comment: Take a look at the header binding approach posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496106/binding-from-headers-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

To address the code duplication and make the code more maintainable in a Spring Boot application, you can create a custom filter to extract and process the common headers before they reach the controllers. Additionally, you can encapsulate the header parameters into an object to enhance code readability and maintainability.

In summary, centralize header processing by creating a `RequestHeaders` DTO, implementing a `CustomHeaderFilter`, and registering it with `FilterRegistrationBean` to apply common headers uniformly across Spring Boot controllers.

Here's a suggested approach:

1. **Create a Header DTO (Data Transfer Object):**

   Define a class that represents the common header parameters. This class will hold the values extracted from the headers.

   ```java
   public class RequestHeaders {
       private String user;
       private String guid;
       private String caller;
       private String language;

       // getters and setters
   }
   ```
2. **Create a Filter:**

   Implement a filter to intercept incoming requests and extract the common headers, then store them in the request attributes.

   ```java
   import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
   import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
   import java.io.IOException;

   public class CustomHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
       @Override
       protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
               throws ServletException, IOException {

           RequestHeaders headers = new RequestHeaders();
           headers.setUser(request.getHeader("user"));
           headers.setGuid(request.getHeader("guid"));
           headers.setCaller(request.getHeader("caller"));
           headers.setLanguage(request.getHeader("language"));

           request.setAttribute("requestHeaders", headers);

           filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Register the Filter using FilterRegistrationBean:**

   Register the custom filter using `FilterRegistrationBean` in your main application class.

   ```java
   import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

   @Configuration
   public class WebConfig {
       @Bean
       public FilterRegistrationBean<CustomHeaderFilter> customHeaderFilter() {
           FilterRegistrationBean<CustomHeaderFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
           registrationBean.setFilter(new CustomHeaderFilter());
           registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/*"); // Adjust the URL pattern as needed
           return registrationBean;
       }
   }
   ```

   Customize the `addUrlPatterns` method to match the URLs you want the filter to be applied to.
4. **Modify Controllers to Use the DTO:**

   Modify your controllers to use the `RequestHeaders` DTO instead of individual header parameters.

   ```java
   @GetMapping("/products/{comp}")
   public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts(@PathVariable @NotNull Integer comp,
                                                       @ModelAttribute("requestHeaders") RequestHeaders headers) {
       return ResponseEntity.ok(service.get(comp, headers));
   }

   @GetMapping("/products")
   public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts(@ModelAttribute("requestHeaders") RequestHeaders headers) {
       return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getAllRecords(headers));
   }
   ```

Now, if you need to add a new header parameter or make changes, you only need to update the `RequestHeaders` class and the filter logic. This approach centralizes the header processing and enhances maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach to make the controller's interface independent from the number of headers:

```
@GetMapping("/products/{comp}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts(
        @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers,
        @PathVariable @NotNull Integer comp
) {
    MyHeaders headers = MyHeaders(headers);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.get(comp, ProductUtils.processHeaders(headers.getUser,headers.getGuid,headers.getCaller,headers.getLanguage)));

}
```

You will need to implement MyHeaders classes as shared components.

Comment: I got your point, however this approach does not help if you want to document the API (swagger)